# JAX-RS How to return a list as Json with field name

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, javax.ws.rs

I have a list which I want to return as a Response. But I want to prepend it with a field name.

```
List<String> res = ...
return Response.ok(res, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
```

This returns only the list

```
["abcd","efgh"]
```

But I want to return like

```
{
  "field" : ["abcd","efgh"]
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Wrap it with a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map.

```
List<String> list = ...
Map<String, List<String>> res = new HashMap<>();
res.put("field", list);
return Response.ok(res, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
```

Comment: Oh. It was simple. Didn't think in this way. Was trying with JsonNode and ObjectNode

Comment: You could also define a class with a list, and then serialize the object.